# C code - Issue applying coloring to font in string

Tags: c, syntax, fonts, colors, format

I'm working with some code from an 18 year old game so I apologize for what may ultimately be caused from deprecated syntax among many other possibilities. But I'm trying to apply coloring to certain text that historically didn't have any. Below are a few examples that I'll explaining.

Example 1 (working with colored font):

```
putMovieText ( client, 
               movie, 
               "|c60|%s tried to flee but can't! (%d%% chance)|c43| ",
               client->getName(), chance );
```

Example 2 (item in it's original state, pre applying font coloring):

```
switch ( affect->source ) 
{
    case _AFF_SOURCE_PERMANENT: 
        strcat( str, "Permed with ");
        break;
```

Example 3 (Red font applied and returned back to original state):

```
switch ( affect->source ) 
{
    case _AFF_SOURCE_PERMANENT: 
        strcat( str, "|c60|Permed with|c43|");
        break;
```

So the font will react to things such as line breaks (\n) but not applying color (see example 2/3). The format/syntax of |c60| works elsewhere in the code but not for the above examples.

Thoughts?

Comment: `"|cNN|"` is definitely not a standard terminal color code. I suspect that `putMovieText()` is translating these tags into a terminal color code. Are you passing the result of the `strcat()` to `putMovieText()` or are you using some other I/O functions?

Comment: It is not a matter of deprecated syntax.  You appear to have proprietary mark-up in a string - as far as C language is concerned a string is just a string. and `"|c60|"` has no special meaning.  You might replace them with common terminal emulator escape sequences - which will work for execution environments that support them.  For example `"\x1B[31mRed Text Here"`.

Comment: @EOF , so the result itself is not being passed to putMovieText. Other examples that utilize color are not passing it to putMovieText either, the example I shared though did pass it. Another example below I can't find a rhyme or reason as to why color works in, below 

```    if ( curLevel != endLevel ) {char temp[1024]; sprintf ( sizeof ( temp ), temp, "|c60|%s %s|c43| ", getName(), dmgMsgs[endLevel] );
strcat ( str, temp );```

Comment: Avoid adding relevant information in comments.  This is not a discussion forum.  Add the example to the question.  Include information about your tool-chain.  The assertion lacks plausibility - is there perhaps some sort of pre-processor that converts this string mark-up to platform specific code?

Comment: What is the execution environment?

Comment: Ubuntu 16 release